public bool HadCachedComponent<T>(out T component), how to make it faster?
Some of end users calling multiple times TryGetComponent on my Target class.(Target class is attached to hundreds of targets)
IOT make they life easier was thinking about caching components which they requesting instread to using TryGetComponent on each frame,so:

in my Target class, added:
     readonly Dictionary<Type, object> m_cachedComponents = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public bool HadCachedComponent<T>(out T component)
        {
            var componentType = typeof(T);

            if (m_cachedComponents.TryGetValue(componentType, out var obj))
            {
                component = (T)obj;
                return obj != null;
            }

            if (TryGetComponent<T>(out component))
            {
                m_cachedComponents.TryAdd(componentType, component);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_cachedComponents.TryAdd(componentType, null);
                return false;
            }
        }

code working as expected, and storing reference to requested by end-users components but it's slight slower than normal GetComponent, any advice how to make it faster?
OFC was using single component like this:
        bool m_wasEnabled_CachedStealthComponent = false;
        bool m_had_CachedStealthComponent = false;
        Stealth m_stealth;
        public bool Cached_StealthComponent(out Stealth _stealth)
        {
            if (!m_wasEnabled_CachedStealthComponent)
            {
                m_had_CachedStealthComponent = TryGetComponent<Stealth>(out m_stealth);
                m_wasEnabled_CachedStealthComponent = true;
            }
            _stealth = m_stealth;
            return m_had_CachedStealthComponent;
        }

they are fast, and easy but required hardcoding all of components....
as written above had code solution but is not fast enough

Some of end users calling multiple times TryGetComponent can't you just tell your users to not do this? ^^ The same as with how to use GetComponent etc in general without being your specific class, the best practice is to cash and reuse the reference instead of calling it hundred of times every frame ...

Also why NonExistentMarker instead of simply null which per Unity API definitions means the same .. would reduce some redundant checks and casting - in the end you anyway return component = default which will be null ... you should just directly use Component instead of object and make T limited to where T : Component (unless you will have to support interfaces)

Thx for your time. Totally understand your suggestion, but is quite not answer for my question.

Well you wanted to know how to make your code faster ... and using null instead of NonExistentMarker would as said remove some complexity and type check (instead obj is NonExistentMarker you would simply do component = obj as T; return component != null; .. of course any complexity you add will be slightly slower than plain using GetComponent / TryGetComponent ... question is how severe is this as it will only be slow the first time I guess - otherwise as said I would claim User fault as for any expensive thing called in Update without caching properly

Hi sry for previous comment, was cutt off during editing by my kids. Added this NonExistentMarker IOT prevent from again calling TryGetComponent. For sure will test out your suggestions. Again thx for your time and sorry if my comment was rude.

Updated version of bool was pasted in initial question.... hate this formating in lines view...
unfortunately no performance gain, actual call on dictionary seems to be slower than TryGetComponent...

While a Dictionary has a constant time complexity O(1), but it's not necessarily faster than everything else. Especially when you only have a handfull of components on a single gameobject, the dictionary overhead may be larger than just iteratint through an array when you only have something like 5 to 10 elements. Dictionaries are great when you're dealing with large "n" as the complexity stays constant.
A potential solution may be to use source generators to create specific "shortcut" properties like the method you mentioned.
Another would be to wrap the logic in a custom class and create an specific instance for each type you're interested in. But it would require some custom initialization in Awake or the constructor.
We don't know the exact implementation of GetComponent on the native side, but it's most likely just iterating through a C++ vector of all the components on the gameobject until it finds the type in question. For a small number of components you probably can't get faster besides a single dedicated cached variable.

GetComponent became significantly faster I think close to Unity 2017 when they introduced some compile time hashing so it is definitely better than just iterating through components - there already is some sort of hash map in place .. so actually I don't think you can get much faster than that
